# Связанные страницы в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

делаю небольшой магазин на wordpress, одно из главных требований заказчика, чтобы характеристики товаров были на отдельных страницах (нужно для SEO, что-бы распределить ключевики).

Есть страница "Арматура 6мм", и должна быть вторая страница "Характеристики арматуры 6мм". Эти страницы обязательно должны иметь ссылки друг на друга ("Посмотреть характеристики" и "купить этот товар" соответсвенно).

Как правильнее будет построить архитектуру? Как лучше свзязать эти старинцы, может есть какие-то готовые плагины?

Товаров будет около 8К, поэтому все ссылки должны будут подставляться автоматически (импорт из экселя).

Так же желательно чтобы ссылки имели вид "domen.ru/armatura6mm" для страницы с товаром, и "domen.ru/armatura6mm/specifications" для страницы с характеристиками, конечно если это возможно.

[image: Страница товара]

[image: Страница с характеристиками]

Comment: Убивать надо таких заказчиков и тех исполнителей, которые не в состоянии донести до них  античеловечность такого подхода. Ида "для сео" никакой выгоды не будет Будет наоборот

Comment: Обычные дочерние страницы чем не устраивают?